# Javascript - schedule Scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a calendar. I am having difficulty on making the calender container scroll. The javascript generates dates in the schedule date container where it contains all the dates. It will also generate a full size calender under where it can show various objects inside. The issue I am having is that I'm trying to get the scrolling to work. When i click on a number in the schedule date container, it will scroll the full size calender to that specific date, but I am having difficulty coding the scrolling part. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
<p>
<div id='schedule-date-background'>
<div id='schedule-date-container'>
</div>
</div>
<div id="schedule-overall-frame">
<div id='schedule-overall-container'>
</div>
</div>
</p>
```

// JavaScript Document$(document).ready(function () {

```
//Global Variables
var week = [14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27];
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
//End of Global Variable

//Dates loaders
function LoadDates()
{ 
    for (var i = 0; i < week.length; i++)
        {
                            //add <div id="today"> to the schedule 
            if (day==week[i]){
                var ObjDiv = $('<div></div>');
                ObjDiv.addClass(i);
                ObjDiv.addClass("schedule-date-minicontainer");
                ObjDiv.addClass("today");
                ObjDiv.append(week[i]);
                $('#schedule-date-container').append(ObjDiv);
            }
                            //generate dates
            else{
                var ObjDiv = $('<div></div>');
                ObjDiv.addClass(i);
                ObjDiv.addClass("schedule-date-minicontainer");
                ObjDiv.append(week[i]);
                $('#schedule-date-container').append(ObjDiv);
            }
    }     

    var container = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<week.length; i++)
    {  

        var ObjDiv = $('<div></div>');
        ObjDiv.addClass("schedule-stripcontainer");
        ObjDiv.append(week[i]);
        $('#schedule-overall-container').append(ObjDiv);
        if (day==week[i]){
            container = "230" * (i-1);

        }

    }

    /*document.getElementById("schedule-overall-container").style.marginLeft = -container + "px" ;*/
    $('div#schedule-overall-container').animate({'left': -container}, 'slow')



} 
  //End of Dates Loader


    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName('0').click(function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName('0').animate({'left': '+=230px'}, 'slow');
        $('div#schedule-overall-container').animate({'left': '+=230px'}, 'slow');

    });


    $('.1').click(function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName.animate({'left': '+=230px'}, 'slow');
        $('div#schedule-overall-container').animate({'left': '+=230px'}, 'slow');
    });
```

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net/9GCYE/27/ of it so that it would be easy to work on it.. have made it but no css??

Comment: Thank you for replying man. I've updated jsfiddle.